# Bootstrap 5: NAV items do not align to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, alignment

How to move the nav items to the right side?

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and use the navigation feature. By default, the items are aligned on the left but I want to put them on the right side. I already used `navbar-right` `float: right;` and `ml-auto` even if its on Bootstrap 4. Here is what the navbar look like in the website

[image: this is what the website looks like]

And this is what my code looks like:

[image: this is what my code looks like]

(NOTE: it will only move to the right if I don't put it inside the `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">` but I need them to be in there.)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />

  <title>Investigation Management and Alert Site</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          Investigation Management and Alert Site
        </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inspections</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here are a few thinks you should keep in mind:

- The `ml-auto` class was used in Bootstrap 4 and `navbar-right` in Bootstrap 3. With Bootstrap 5 the classnames changed, so you should use `ms-auto` for this (see [Bootrap 5 Migration](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#utilities))
- Classes must not be comma separated in the HTML. Comma-separation for classes only applies as a CSS-selector.
- I would recommend to use a icon font or use a single svg-icon for the user-icon. The reason for that is that svg-icons can be scaled without pixelation, they have a much smaller size and are generally a better idea for this use-case in terms of SEO and accessability.
- Remember to close all tags correctly (in your code you close the `ul`-tag two times).
- In the future, try to post your code in a form so that others can copy it easily. With images one might need to type everything by hand if one wants to help you.

I hope that helped you a bit. If not or if you got any questions, feel free to ask. Keep it up!

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much, Sir! I thought no one will help me. I'll try to fix my code now. Thank you again and for the tips too. If I encounter any errors I'll let you know. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Use The "flex-row-reverse" class in the mother div. It'll change the position of child items of mother div.
Screenshot - https://prnt.sc/uZi6oR9evyaJ

Use the Nav Markup for Desktop & Mobile devices

```
<nav class="navbar d-lg-flex navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Site Logo
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse w-100 navbar-collapse flex-row-reverse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link menu-item nav-active">Our Solution</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link menu-item">How We Help</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link menu-item">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link menu-item">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```